# Office.js iterate single cells in a single column in a table

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I have a control panel within an excel sheet as part of my addin this is built when the addin starts. 
I would like to make sure all my code references the the sheet are relative references so if a user adds a column to the control pannel or moves it. The addin still works.

For example If I want to Read information:

```
    // This reads a list of tickers to than query my back end for data.
    let BBTickerRange=sheet.tables.getItem("ControlPanel").columns.getItem("Symbol Ticker");
    BBTickerRange.load(["values", "columns", "items"])

     // IF the lookup misses I have code like
                BloombergTableOne.columns.items[i + 1].name = ("#TK" + i + " " + BBTickerRange.values[i][0]);
                BloombergTableOne.columns.getItemAt(i + 1).getHeaderRowRange().format.fill.color = "#DD5D74";
                BloombergTableOne.columns.getItemAt(i + 1).getDataBodyRange().clear();

     // But for Changing a specific value within the control panel I am still using code like
          var SymStartDate = sheet.getRange("D12:D12").getOffsetRange(i, 0);
          var SymEndDate = sheet.getRange("E12:E12").getOffsetRange(i, 0);
```

I would like to have this to look at a specific column in the sheet and than iterate over the rows rater than having to do a generic reference and an offset.

Is there a way to iterate to change single values within a column without writing the entire .getDataBodyRange

Answer (score 0):

```
// Potential Solution for anyone looking for a workaround.       
let SymStartDateCol=  sheet.tables.getItem("ControlPanel").columns.getItem("Start Date").getHeaderRowRange().load(["address"]); 
   //SymStartDateCol.load(["values", "columns", "items", "address"])
let SymEndDateCol=  sheet.tables.getItem("ControlPanel").columns.getItem("End Date").getHeaderRowRange().load(["address"]);
```

return context.sync()
          .then(async (Symbol) => {

```
var SymStartDate = sheet.getRange(SymStartDateCol.address).getOffsetRange(i+1, 0);
var SymEndDate = sheet.getRange(SymEndDateCol.address).getOffsetRange(i+1, 0);
```